# Identifier Expected Error in Line 29

Tags: java, identifier

This is a program that has the user input a sentence then choose a character. It then tells the user how many times that character comes up but I am having trouble with one error since its expected an identifier. This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringTest{
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner incomingString = new Scanner( System.in);
System.out.print("Type Something");
String s1 = incomingString.nextLine();
Scanner s2incomingString = new Scanner( System.in);
System.out.print("Choose a character"); 
String s2 = s2incomingString.nextLine();    

String result="";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1);
int counter = 0;
int start = 0;
int index = 0;

while (s1.length != -1){
 int counter = 0;
     index = s1.indexOf(s2,start);
     if (index != -1){
        counter++;
        start = index+1;
        }
     }    
 }
    System.out.println(index);         
}
```

Comment: Please tell us which is line 29 - and indent your source code when you post. It's *really* hard to read at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the immediate problem:

```
System.out.println(index);
```

It exists outside the body of any method, constructor or initializer - you can't do that. I suspect you meant it to be in the body of the `main` method.

This is *much* more obvious if you indent your code. Here's your code, indented appropriately (and skipping a bunch in the middle):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner incomingString = new Scanner( System.in);
        ...
        int index = 0;

        while (s1.length != -1){
            int counter = 0;
            index = s1.indexOf(s2,start);
            if (index != -1){
                counter++;
                start = index+1;
            }
        }    
    }
    System.out.println(index);         
}
```

See how the `System.out.println` call is at the same level as you'd expect a method declaration? *Always* indent your code - most IDEs can do this for you as you type, or on demand. It makes things better for everyone.

Having fixed the problem by moving that statement inside the closing brace of the `main` method, you'll then see two more problems:

- You're declaring `counter` twice, where the second declaration is in a place where the first declaration is already in scope.
- You're using `String.length` as if it were a field, not a method; change `s1.length` to `s1.length()`

The code will then *compile*... it isn't clear what you're trying to do though, and `String.length()` will never return -1... Perhaps you wanted like `while (index != -1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
s1.length
```

but `length()` is a method, not a field for `String`.

```
s1.length()
```

is what you want. Also, you are declaring the duplicate variable `counter`. You can only declare once within a local scope.

Comment: While those are both true, they're not the cause of the OP's immediate problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. I'll leave this up in hopes that it'll help him after he fixes his bigger problem(s).